# Regex expression to find

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a Java program that replaces variable values in a text file.

The variables to be replaced are encapsulated as...

```
 side    /*{{*/ red /*TEAM}}*/
```

or

```
detect_range   /*{{*/ 200 /*RANGE}}*/  nm
```

So in the first case I want to replace the value red with another value. The second I would replace 200.

Here I am reading the file line by line looking for that pattern.

```
       File file = new File(currentFile);

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);


        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            if (<match regex expression for xxxxx /*{{*/ value /*VariableNAME}}*/ >) {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        //handle this
    }
```

What is a regex expression to that I Could use to find these patterns?

Edit:

I have a line in the file that would say

```
side    /*{{*/ red /*TEAM}}*/
```

The output change the line in the file to

```
side    /*{{*/ blue /*TEAM}}*/
```

The string "TEAM" is the identifier.

Comment: the `/* */` pairs, are they part of the pattern, or just comment markers?

Comment: Is `TEAM` and `RANGE` are dynamic value?

Comment: You need to specify the problem more clearly.  Show some examples of actual input ***and*** the expected output and explain how the replacement values are mapped to the tags they replace.

Comment: TEAM and RANGE are are just variable names. I must retrieve the variable names to know what values to append to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below use with `String.replaceAll()` method.

```
(?<=\/\*\{\{\*\/ ).*?(?= \/\*(TEAM|RANGE)\}\}\*\/)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/wC5vM7/4)

**Note:** Use `\w+` if value "TEAM" and "RANGE" are dynamic.

---

Sample code:

```
String str1 = "side    /*{{*/ red /*team}}*/ ";
String str2 = "detect_range   /*{{*/ 200 /*RANGE}}*/  nm";
String pattern = "(?i)(?<=\\/\\*\\{\\{\\*\\/ ).*?(?= \\/\\*(TEAM|RANGE)\\}\\}\\*\\/)";
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll(pattern, "XXX"));
System.out.println(str2.replaceAll(pattern, "000"));
```

output:

```
side    /*{{*/ XXX /*team}}*/ 
detect_range   /*{{*/ 000 /*RANGE}}*/  nm
```

---

If you want to get "TEAM" or "RANGE" then get it from index 1.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str1);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: How could I extract the variable name "team" for example, to compare it to know what value to insert.

Comment: just get the matched group from index 1 as shown in demo as well. Do you need code as well?

Comment: That would be helpful.

Comment: In the pattern 
String pattern = "(?i)(?<=\\/\\*\\{\\{\\*\\/ ).*?(?= \\/\\*(TEAM|RANGE)\\}\\}\\*\\/)";

Could I replace TEAM|RANGE with a wildcard so that it would match no matter what the variable name is?

Comment: yes you can use it, as I mentioned use `\w+` instead of `(TEAM|RANGE)`. Are you looking for only variable names then I can optimize it, if you need?

Comment: Yes, Im looking for any line in the text file that matches that pattern. Then I will get the variable name and compare it to a list of names that I have values for. Finally I will replace the variable value inline. \w+ Does work here, thanks.

Comment: so the pattern consists this `/*{{*/ any_string /*any_variable_name}}*/` form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/\*{{\*/ *(\S+) */\*[^}]*}}\*/
```

and grab captured group #1

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bD0vA3/1)